# macro that applies only once

Tags: c++

Is it possible to write a macro, that applies exactly once no matter how many times it is nested?

```
// how to implement this properly?
#define FOO(x) hello(x) // incorrect, works only for 1 level of nesting

// desired use below
void hello(int x);
FOO(x); // expanded to "hello(x)"
FOO(FOO(x)); // also expanded to "hello(x)", not "hello(hello(x))"
FOO(FOO(FOO(x))); // also expanded to "hello(x)"
```

Are there any alternatives to the implementation of `FOO`, maybe not as a macro, but some C++ template that can achieve the same effect?

---

Why do I need this?

I am writing clang libTooling source to source transformations that enclose some variables uses into my own wrapper. For example, I have the following fragment of code: `a[3] = 5;`

it is transformed to `hello(a)[3] = 5;` and the meaning and behavior of `hello` is controlled by me.
However, if I have the following fragment of code

```
#define A a[3] 
A = 4;
A = 5;
A = 6;
```

then due to limitations of clang libTooling, I have to add change to the macro body like this:

```
#define A hello(a)[3] 
A = 4;
A = 5;
A = 6;
```

Unfortunately, this is not easy to achieve, because the pattern is matched 3 times and it is not obvious how to distinguish them in the general case, so everything ends like this:

```
#define A hello(hello(hello(a)))[3] 
A = 4;
A = 5;
A = 6;
```

This is obviously not what I want, so I am looking for workarounds. I hope the design of some macro like `FOO` could solve the problem with the least effort.

Comment: AFAIK, no.  If you want to run something once, you should look into [`std::call_once`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once)

Comment: Why do you need something like that? Just don't type `FOO(FOO`.

Comment: Please, describe what you're trying to do in more detail, with context.

Comment: @KamilCuk I added an explanation of my use case for it.

Comment: Preprocessing is a lightweight tool for convenience, not a full tool for programming. Avoid screwing around with it.

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++. You accepted a C++ answer, and now people interested in C who find this question in the future will be frustrated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could overload a function on type of argument. With a special type, you could just forward it, only calling the function when actual arguments are provided.

```
void hello(int x);

struct FOO_hello_called {};
FOO_hello_called FOO(int x) {
   hello(x);
   return {};
}
FOO_hello_called FOO(FOO_hello_called s) {
   return s;
}

int main() {
    int x = 1;
    FOO(x); // calls "hello(x)"
    FOO(FOO(x)); // calls "hello(x)" once
    FOO(FOO(FOO(x))); // also calls "hello(x)" once
}
```